# Linkedin iOS App in-App browser not allowing to donwload zip files

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview, linkedin-api

I'm having an issue with a website I built. If someone click on a post linking to my website, the iOS App opens the site in the in-App browser. When click on a link in the website to download a zip file, the browser attempts to open the file as text and you only see garbled text.

I tested it on the Android app and it works fine there.

Any advice is Welcomed. Do we need to report this as a bug in LinkedIn? Has anyone found anything related to this in the official LinkedIn documentation (I haven't).

---

My short term solution is to detect if the user is browsing on IOS using the LinkedIn App with this code:

Having a link

```
<a id="download-file" href="...my-download.zip" download>Download your report</a>
```

Javascript:

```
const isIOS = typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
const isLinkedinApp = typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && (/LinkedInApp/i.test(navigator.userAgent));

if (isIOS && isLinkedinApp) {
      document.getElementById("download-report").remove();
}
```